Installing pip2 or pip3 removes the other on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
So I am rather new regarding linux and I am installing pip2 and pip3 on my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I have both python2.7 and 3 installed (triple checked that they work etc). When I install pip2 or 3 it removes the other which is unusual to my understanding. Here are the logs for that:
Start-Date: 2024-04-25  03:05:47
Commandline: apt install python-pip
Requested-By: capstone (1000)

Install: python-pip:amd64 (20.3.4+dfsg-4)

Remove: python3-pip:amd64 (22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.4)

End-Date: 2024-04-25  03:05:48

Here is what the installation says:
capstone@capstone-virtual-machine:/$ sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython2-stdlib libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1 python-pkg-resources
  python-setuptools python2 python2-minimal

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.

The following packages will be REMOVED:
  
python-pip

The following NEW packages will be installed:

  python3-pip

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not 
upgraded.

Need to get 1 305 kB of archives.

After this operation, 2 153 kB of additional disk space will be used.

So what am I doing wrong?

So I realised I didn't check If pip3 was installed somewhere else.
capstone@capstone-virtual-machine:/$ find / -name pip3 2>/dev/null
Output: /snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr/bin/pip3
So pip3 is located here. At this point am I just doing pointless task by trying to install pip3 in /usr/bin/ ?

No, using stuff from snap can bite you at any moment. Unfortunately, currently python-pip and python3-pip packages are incompatible. That might be related to the fact that on a modern distro pip is already pip3, and python-pip is trying to provide pip binary for python 2. If I were you, I'd just install pip for your python3 from apt (python3-pip) and then use pyenv to set up python2.7 and its pip. It's now obsolete and old, so you likely don't need it often. How are you going to use python 2?

Thanks for quick reply! So we have our robotics program (not going too much into details) and we require both pip2 and 3 because of how old the robots libraries etc are. So it will be used regularly. I will try the pyenv way.

Well yes, then you will definitely have to manage virtual environments anyway - pyenv is probably the easiest way to support venvs for different python versions without hassle.

Even if you do have the 2 virtual environments, you can't use python 2 and python 3 in the same program.  What you're describing is two separate python applications that communicate via some IPC mechanism.  I know nothing of robotics libs, but 2.7 is ancient.  Isn't there some other library, perhaps in some other easy-to-use language?
